# Difference between the Peer Review badge and the Custodian badge

Tags: support, badges

I thought that the difference between the *Peer Review* Badge and the *Custodian* badge would be like this:

**Peer Review** (First review of someone else's proposed change): You accept/ deny an edit of someone to your own post

**Custodian** (Complete at least one review task. This badge is awarded once per review type): You complete a review task [in the Review section](https://stackoverflow.com/review)

So when I reviewed documentation changes today (for the first time) I was awarded with the *Peer Review* badge and not the *Custodian* one.

Is this a bug or am I getting the badge descriptions wrong?

I could understand getting both badges at one documentation review job. That would make sense to me: a review task from the documentation is *kind of* a review of someone else´s change.

Comment: Regarding your edit, I am confused what you find unclear about the current answer. They are essentially the same badge, but one is for Documentation and the other for regular SO (Q&A).

Comment: Okay I guess I get it now: the _Custodian_ was awarded for an edit on my post I approved and the _Peer Review_ for reviewing documentation changes. I just thought it would be the other way round, because of the link from the description

Comment: Where is this link you keep mentioning? The only one i see from the badge page sends you to the regular Q&A review. If there is another description somewhere else that sends you to docs, utneeds fixed

Comment: I meant the [link at the badge description](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2278/custodian) (I guess this is what you meant too). What troubled me: When I tried to get the _Custodian_ badge I followed the link in the description and did as I thought I have to, for getting the badge. When I recieved another badge I was a bit confused...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [*Peer Review*](//stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5854) badge is for Documentation.
The [*Custodian*](//stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2278) badge is for posts in the main body of the site.

So, because you reviewed a Documentation proposal you correctly received *Peer Review*.  Peer Review is one of the new badges that were introduced when the Documentation feature was added to SO.  These are only available on SO.

There are also other Documentation badges that could be seen as mirrors of other "normal" badges.  e.g. *Backer* is a mirror of *Supporter*; *Educated* is a mirror of *Informed*.

A description of the badges is also available on [the Main Meta site](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397):

- [Custodian](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732)
- [Peer Review](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/281615)

Comment: But wouldn´t the description suggest it´s the other way around? Even if i set _Custodian_ as my tracked badge and click on the link I am redirected to the documentation page.

Comment: I know where to find the description, I posted it up there in my question :)

Comment: **And**: please explain what are the referred  review types in the description of the _Custodian_ if not the categories of the review section of SO.

Comment: @creyD Once you have 500 reputation, you’ll be able to see the other review queues.